# Why were my upvoted answers deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

Today, a few hours ago, I had 159 reputation on Stack Overflow. But now I have only 114, as two of my answers are deleted by the moderator. These answers were upvoted also. What is the reason for deletion, and how I can avoid this in the future?

Comment: We can only comment on this when we have a link to the actual answers ...

Comment: Your answers don't contain actual answers. They are just *pointers* to an answer. That falls apart when the memory gets overwritten...err, when the link goes down. We expect all answers on Stack Overflow to be self-contained, with the answer to the question written right in the body of the answer. Therefore, you can link to off-site resources, but you need to *summarize* the answer within the answer itself. If it's something short, quote from the link (using proper blockquote formatting and explicitly crediting the original author).

Comment: @Cody, never thought about it that way, but indeed we aim to always write answers *by value*.

Comment: It is good to see, that you can use a quite good writing quality, if you really want.

Comment: Thx @peterh I will try to improve it in future.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39228182/16587) was deleted because the answer contains no information inside of it; the most it provides is a link to somewhere else.

Someone even commented letting you know it wasn't a good answer.

Same thing with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38876416/16587), and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38692833/16587).